# Combine STS and relying party into same website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wif

I'm working on an MVC project and I'd like to abstract authentication out completely using WIF. By default, without any additional configuration, this app needs to be it's own STS in additional to also being a relying party. Has anyone done that and have any suggestions?

Comment: @ElYusubov: a Security Token Service. a common notion.

Comment: Struggling to get my head around this! On the one hand, you want the app. to outsource authentication. On the other hand you want the app. to include it. What's the underlying requirement that drives this? Can't you deploy the app. and the STS on the same IIS?

Comment: You're right, the power of WIF is in outsourcing authentication. However, why can't you just outsource that to part of yourself rather than to just a separate application? The requirement is that the app needs to be self contained while allowing for outside authentication so I need to include a small STS inside the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to think of exactly the same mechanism some time ago and I failed.

My reasoning was that to be an RP, the application has to get a signed SAML token issued by an STS. Upon receiving the token, the federation cookie is created.

But to be the STS, the application should have a login page and a mechanism to persist the login session so that users do not have to login again. Then it should react to `wsignin1.0` requests and issue SAML tokens.

This leads to a contradiction in my opinion. The application should have a federation cookie (to maintain users sessions as an STS) before it issues the SAML token but in the same time it can create a federation cookie (as an RP) just after it receives the SAML token.

Of course, you could possibly maintain two cookies, a federation cookie for the RP part and a forms cookie (probably) for the STS part but it sounds impractical and against the idea of abstracting the authentication.

In a short way: this is not easily possible in my opinion. However, I would be glad to hear other ideas from someone.

Comment: This was the same conclusion I came to as I was thinking about how to do it.